# One-word synonym (instead of compound adjectives) for "time-consuming" and "less time-consuming"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

For 'time-consuming', I tried http://thesaurus.com/browse/time-consuming.

For 'less time-consuming', I tried researching synonyms for 'productive' (http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/productive).

But none of the above results  pertain to time.

**Example of '(less) time-consuming' upon request:**

As Googling each bus route (e.g. in Hong Kong, London) is too  time-consuming, what are some less time-consuming methods to see all the bus routes on the same map?

Comment: Protracted vs fleeting? If those aren't exactly what you're looking for, you might have better luck searching a thesaurus for them?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @bib This was more an attempt to get more info and context from the OP rather than provide a definitive answer. I suppose I could delete the comment and post it as an answer if it bothers you.

Comment: Arduous is another.

Comment: @JackRyan: I've updated my OP. Better?

Comment: @KevinWorkman: I've updated my OP. Better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**More Time-Consuming**

I can perhaps offer a few alternatives, in this order:

1. *Protracted* = drawn out considerably, particularly in time.
2. *Exhaustive* = comprehensive or thorough, but draining.
3. *Laborious* ~ (As above - @Preetie Sekhon)

**Less Time-Consuming**

Again, in this order:

1. *Transient* = brief, not lasting very long at all.
2. *Ephemeral* = lasting a very short time, very brief, transitory.
3. *Brief* = very fast, short-lived.

**Caution**

Be careful with *ephemeral* in particular, because almost no one typically knows what that means.  It is a very uncommon word.

Comment: Another one to add is arduous

Comment: Very uncommon might be an overstatement. If anything I'd just say the problem is people can confuse it with ethereal.

Answer (score 2):

You could describe a time-consuming task as *involved* or potentially *engrossing* for something that might be involuntarily time-consuming.

For something less time-consuming, I would think *easy*, *quick*, or *simple* might work.

Answer (score 1):

More time consuming :

**laborious**

*requiring considerable time and effort.*

Cannot think of anything for requiring less time

**effortless** is something that does not require much energy or inputs.

Speedy
 *done or occurring quickly* , may also work, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

***[tedious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tedious)*** (M-W):

> boring and too slow or long

***[quick](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick)***: this is obvious but here's a definition for completeness sake (M-W):

> done or happening in a short amount of time

Your examples:

Inasmuch as it'd be ***tedious*** to Google each individually,

what are some ***quick*** ways to find bestselling French nonfiction (either originally written in or translated into French) which are available as audiobooks?